# Bootstrap modal interfering with droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-droppable

I have draggables and droppables on a page with a bootstrap modal.  They work fine on page load.  However, if the modal is opened and closed, they no longer work.  For this reason, I have placed them inside an init() function which I run after modal close.  This works for the draggables, but not the droppables.  To be clear, after draggableInit() runs the second time, I can drag, but not drop.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    draggableInit();
});

// Reinitialize draggables after modal close
$('#gallery-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    draggableInit();
});

function draggableInit() {
    // Draggable
    $('.block-grab').draggable({
        containment: 'document',
        stack: '.edit-container',
        revert: true,
        refreshPositions: true,
        start: function(event, ui) {
            ui.helper.data('not-dropped', true);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.helper.data('not-dropped')) {
                $('.dz').hide();
            }
        }
    });
    // Droppable
    $.each($('.dz-container'), function() {
        var hbid = $(this).data('hbid');
        var position = $(this).data('position');
        $('#dz-'+position+'-container-'+hbid).droppable({
            over: function() {
                $('#dz-'+position+'-'+hbid).show().droppable({
                    accept: '.block-grab', 
                    drop: blockDropped 
                }); 
            },
            out: function() { 
                $('#dz-'+position+'-'+hbid).hide(); 
            },
        });
    });
    function blockDropped(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.data('not-dropped', false);
        ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
        $(this).droppable('disable');
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    
        var hbid = $(this).data('hbid');
        var position = $(this).data('position');
        var type = ui.draggable.data('type');
        $('#dz-'+position+'-'+hbid).show()
        $.post('/controller/drop-block', { hbid : hbid, position : position, type : type });
    }
}
```

Edit:
It must have something to do with conflicting jquery-ui:
On page load, it loads jquery-ui.min.js
On modal open, it loads jquery-ui.js

Another Edit:
After creating a jQuery modal, I discovered my problem is not a conflict between Bootstrap and jquery, but something in the gallery plugin that I am placing in the modal.

Comment: *"On page load, it loads jquery-ui.min.js On modal open, it loads jquery-ui.js"*

Why are you using two different jQuery UI files?

Comment: @Skully I thought Bootstrap was calling the second jQuery UI.  It turns out it's the gallery plugin I'm using.  That must be the issue.  I need look more into it.

Comment: @Skully  Yes, that was issue.  I'm fairly new to js and jQuery, so I'm a bit slow on the uptake. :-)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)